# Automatically move deleted Outlook items to archive folder after two weeks

Tags: microsoft-outlook, vba

Is there way to set up a rule in Outlook to automatically move my deleted items and sent items after a certain amount of time, say two weeks, to an archive folder?

If it can't be done with a rule does anyone know how to do it in VBA?

Comment: Just those 2 specific folders?

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't this be done with Auto Archiving? You can set the interval of Auto Archive to 14 days, and turn it on only for the folders that you want. Items in the Deleted Items folder can even be handled this way, if you want.

Comment: As mentioned in the NOTE on this [Microsoft page](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/automatically-move-or-delete-older-items-with-autoarchive-HA010105706.aspx), you may not be able to use Auto Archive in some situations, specifically when your Exchange server is configured to "restrict users' ability to retain messages and other records beyond a specific period of time that is defined by the organization." Thus I'm looking for an alternate solution.