# How to setup rule to move deleted items to folder outside Outlook 2010?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2010, rules

I have a question identical to the one below, however I cannot use the answer given. I don't know if I should continue in the existing thread, or create a new question. I hope I chose correctly.

[Automatically move deleted Outlook items to archive folder after two weeks](https://superuser.com/questions/131471/outlook-rule-to-automatically-move-deleted-files-to-archive-folder-after-two-week)

The problem is I want to save deleted mails to an folder on my drive, but can't use autoarchive (as suggested in the other thread), since autoarchive is controlled by our IT department, and I don't want to mess with them on this.

Is there any other way to do this? Preferably with a outlook rule (but I'm open to other suggestions)

Comment: Manually you can drag-n-drop mail to a folder and then delete them from Outlook.  If you want to automate it, how do you want to trigger it?

Comment: Manually I can fix it yes, thanks. Preferably I would like to automate it on f.x deletion. E.g. when a mail is deleted it would be saved to the folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this. Outlook rules are for incoming and outgoing messages only. There is a way to create a VBA macro however.